# How to display the available sizes for configurable products with different attribute sets with different attribute code

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, product-attribute, ce-1.9.1.0

I have two attribute sets say
i)Shirts
ii)Pants 
The configurable product options are
 shirt_color/shirt_size 
pant_color/pant_size
 They have one thing in common.[image: Same Attribute Labels]

How to display only the available sizes for each configurable product if available?
So far I tried..

```
<div class='divider'>
               <?php /*?> <?php $cProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
                //check if product is a configurable type or not
        if ($cProduct->getData('type_id') == "configurable")
        {
            //get the configurable data from the product
            $config = $cProduct->getTypeInstance(true);
            //loop through the attributes
            foreach($config->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($cProduct) as $attributes)
            { 
             echo count($attributes["values"])." availables";
                ?>
                            <div class="super_attribute[<?php echo                                                                                               attributes['attribute_id'] ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $attributes['attribute_id'] ?>">
                                <?php
                                foreach($attributes["values"] as $values)
                                {
                                    echo $values["label"];
                                }
                                ?>
                            </div>
                  <?php
            }
        }?><?php */?>

        <?php

         ?> </div>
```

My output was 
[image: Sample Confi g products with configurable options]
I need to fetch only the available sizes.. Need a solution...

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div class="available options">
<?php $cProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());?>
        <?php if ($cProduct->getData('type_id') == "configurable")
        {
 $configAttributesArray = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)-

>getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($_product);?>
        <div class="available-color">
        <?php
        //filter so only Color is left and select the values in the array
$configAttributesFilteredByColor = array_filter($configAttributesArray, function($v) { return $v['label'] == 'Color'; });
$configAttributesFilteredByColorValues = $configAttributesFilteredByColor[key($configAttributesFilteredByColor)]['values'];
if(count($configAttributesFilteredByColorValues)>1){
echo count($configAttributesFilteredByColorValues)." colors available";
}else 
echo "only ". count($configAttributesFilteredByColorValues)." color available";


?>
</div>
<div class="available-size">
            <?php
                //filter so only Size is left and select the values in the array
$configAttributesFilteredBySize = array_filter($configAttributesArray, function($v) { return $v['label'] == 'Size'; });
$configAttributesFilteredBySizeValues = $configAttributesFilteredBySize[key($configAttributesFilteredBySize)]['values'];
//get the configurable product its childproducts
$childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProducts(null,$_product);

//loop the values, and the childproducts and match them
echo 'Size: ';

foreach($configAttributesFilteredBySizeValues as $configAttributeValue){

    echo $configAttributeValue['label'] . ' ';
    $value = $configAttributeValue['value_index'];
    foreach($childProducts as $childProduct){
        if($childProduct->getSize() == $value){
            echo $childProduct->getAttributeText('Size') . ',';
        }
    }
}
}?>
```

Comment: feel free to accept your own answer so that the question does not show up as unanswered anymore